# JavaScript test() Method changes return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am writing a small form validation and for some reason, when I call de test() Method, it returns `true`, and if without changing the input value, when calling the Method again, it returns `false`, then `true` again and so on.

This is the form in `html` it is in a modal:

```
<form class="modal-content" (submit)="dashboard.altaCliente()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="" id="clienteNombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="" id="clienteApellido" placeholder="Apellidos" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="email" name="" id="clienteEmail" placeholder="Correo electronico" class="form-control my-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="" id="clienteDNI" placeholder="DNI" class="form-control">
    <input type="date" name="" id="clienteDate" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="password" name="" id="clientePasswd" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control mt-2">
  <div class="mt-2 alert" role="alert"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir cliente</button>
</form>
```

This is the fragment the function :

```
altaCliente() {
const $inputNombre = $("#clienteNombre");
const $inputApellidos = $("#clienteApellido");
const $inputEmail = $("#clienteEmail");
const $inputDNI = $("#clienteDNI");
const $inputDate = $("#clienteDate");
const $inputPasswd = $("#clientePasswd");
const $msg = $(".alert");
let todoOK = true;
$msg.html("");

$inputNombre.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});
$inputApellidos.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});
$inputEmail.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});
$inputDNI.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});
$inputDate.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});
$inputPasswd.on("focus",function(){$(this).removeClass("is-invalid")});

//Nombre
if ($inputNombre.val() === "") {
  $msg.html($msg.html() + "Nombre vacio<br>").addClass(["alert-danger", "show"]);
  $inputNombre.addClass("is-invalid");
  todoOK = false;
} else if (!this.regexNombre.test($inputNombre.val().toString())) {
  $msg.html($msg.html() + "Nombre mal formado<br>").addClass(["alert-danger", "show"]);
  $inputNombre.addClass("is-invalid");
  todoOK = false;
}
//Apellidos
if ($inputApellidos.val() === "") {
  $msg.html($msg.html() + "Apellidos vacios<br>").addClass(["alert-danger", "show"]);
  $inputApellidos.addClass("is-invalid");
  todoOK = false;
} else if (!this.regexApellidos.test(<string>$inputApellidos.val())) {
  $msg.html($msg.html() + "Apellidos mal formados<br>").addClass(["alert-danger", "show"]);
  $inputApellidos.addClass("is-invalid");
  todoOK = false;
}

if (todoOK) {
  $msg.html("Usuario añadido con éxito<br>").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass(["alert-success", "show"]);
}
}
```

Right now I am only validating name and surname.

The patterns are properties of the typeScript and are:

`/^[aA-zZñÑ]+( [aA-zZñÑ]+)*$/g`

The problem comes with the `else if`, as I have said, `test()` returns `true` then when calling the function again it returns `false`.

To be clear, if for example I write 'John' in the name input and click in the 'send' button it would be valid the first time, invalid the second, valid again the third and so on.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include your HTML and the rest of your jQuery code.

Comment: There you have it @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out that removing the 'g' at the end of the regex pattern solved the problem.

With `/^[aA-zZñÑ]+( [aA-zZñÑ]+)*$/g` , return value oscillate between true and false, but   `/^[aA-zZñÑ]+( [aA-zZñÑ]+)*$/` works properly.